# Docker container can't find my node build directory, how do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Desktop and I'm working with a Nest.js app, when I build my project with `docker-compose build` everything is fine since there are no errors in console, however when I run `docker-compose up -d` my container keeps on failing because it can't find the build directory of my app. The strange thing is that this works perfectly fine in my Windows computer, but my macOS laptop is the one that's failing

```bash
Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/dist/main'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)

    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)

    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

  requireStack: []

}
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3005
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
# Run it
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/tmp/dist/main"]
```

This is my docker-compose file and the folder structure of the project is pretty basic, after I run the npm run build command a dist folder is created at the root of my project.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    my-api:
        build: ./my-api
        container_name: 'my-api'
        restart: always
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: "docker-compose"
            APP_PORT: 3005
        ports:
            - "3005:3005"
            - 9229:9229
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - mysql
```

[image: folderStructure]

Comment: What does your `docker-compose.yaml` look like? What is the directory structure of the directory containing that file look like? The output of `tree` is useful if the hierarchy isn't too complicated.

Comment: Just added the requested information

Comment: We're still missing critical information. What's in your `dist/main` directory? Does it contain an `index.js` file? What happens if you locally run `node dist/main`?

Answer (score 0):

As you set `WORKDIR /tmp` you are currently executing commands in this directory. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

And from what you provided there is no another `tmp` directory in you current working directory.
Try to change last command to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/dist/main"]
```